# How can I build multiple projects with meson?

Tags: meson-build

I started using meson and thought that it was really good, but how can I build multiple projects with one singular `meson.build` file? After reading multiple forums and meson official pages, I haven't concluded anyway of doing what I want.

Just suppose that I have this directory layout:

```
/:
  dummy1:
    ...
    meson.build

  dummy2:
    ...
    meson.build

  meson.build
```

How can `/meson.build` build `/dummy1` and `/dummy2` aswell?

`subproject`s need a wrap file, which needs not only a directory, but a url and a lot more things that i may not need in this case.
`subdir` just panics when it finds a `project` on `/dummy*/meson.build`.
I can't think of any other solution, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639665/how-do-configure-meson-for-a-project-with-multiple-subdirectories), no one answered it yet, even though it was made a month ago. Closing this when the original gets answered.

Comment: see the answer in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639665/how-do-configure-meson-for-a-project-with-multiple-subdirectories/73275236#73275236